# z-index not behaving as expected: data stacking and hiding

Tags: html, css, z-index

the code below demonstrates what i am trying to do. why is my "blackOut" div appearing in front of my "theGoods" div? shouldn't the z-index properly handle this?

```
    <html>

    <head>
        <style>
            table.theGoods{
                display:block;
                z-index:20;
                background-color:yellow;
                font-family:arial;
                font-size:18px;
                width:300px;
                height:300px;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-top:180px;
                text-align:center;

            }


            div.blackOut{
                position:absolute;
                background-color:red;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                padding:0px;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                z-index:2;

            }

            div.behindIt{
                z-index:1;  
                background-color:red;
            }

            #myinnercontainer { position:absolute; top:50%; height:10em; margin-top:-5em }



        </style>
    </head>

        <body>
            <table class="theGoods" id="theGoods">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        la la
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div class="blackOut" id="blackOut" onClick="myHider(event)"></div>

        </body>
    <script>

        function myHider(e){
                document.getElementById("blackOut").style.display="none";
        }

    </script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`z-index:20;` has no effect without either `position:absolute` or `position:relative`. (You want the latter.)

Answer (score 2):

z-index only affects elements with a `position` property other than 'static'. If you add `position:relative;` to table.theGoods, you should be fine. In general, all elements involved in the stacking need to have position:relative or position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use z-index without using:

```
position:absolute;
```

or:

```
position:relative;
```

which is lacking from table.theGoods

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "position: absolute;" to the style for table.theGoods.